# Get some number of records by each type in one jpql query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two entities - Person and Record:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Record> records;
}


@Entity
public class Record {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Person person; 
}
```

And I need to get 5 records for each existing person in one query.

The only solution I've found for jpql looks like this:

```
"SELECT r FROM Person p LEFT JOIN p.records r WHERE r.id IN " +
            "(SELECT r1.id FROM Record r1 WHERE r1.person = p AND " +
            "(SELECT Count(r2) FROM Record r2 WHERE r2.person = r1.person AND r2.id < r1.id) <= 5)
```

But probably there is a more elegant solution in spring jpa.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What `DB` are you using?

Comment: You can do that with a native query and analytic functions fairly easily if your database supports those.

Comment: DB - mysql. And I can't use native query in this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [javax.validation.constraints.Size](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) annotation on the **ToMany** side restricting the **max** bracket

```
//..ToMany and other annotations
@javax.validation.constraints.Size(min=0, max=5)
private List<Record> records;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is unsuitable in my case, since it is not flexible enough, for example, if I'll need to add additional conditions to the query